# How do I convert a complex GROUP BY to Sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

My SQL query is

```
SELECT t."id", t."topicText", COUNT(t."id") AS topicCount 
FROM "WorkbookQuestions" wq, "Workbooks" w, "Questions" q, "Topics" t 
WHERE  w."StudentId" = 3 
  AND wq."QuestionId" = q."id" 
  AND wq."WorkbookId" = w."id" 
  AND q."TopicId" = t."id"
GROUP BY "t"."id"
ORDER BY "topiccount" DESC
```

How can I write this in `Sequelize` code so I can avoid writing SQL directly? Or is it not possible?

This is what I've tried (unsuccessfully) so far:

```
db.WorkbookQuestion.findAll({
  attributes: ['Topics.id', [db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.sequelize.col('Topics.id'))], 'TopicCount'],
  include: [
    {
      model: db.Workbook,
      where: {
        StudentId: newWorkbook.StudentId,
        SubjectId: newWorkbook.SubjectId
      }
    }, {
      model: db.Question,
      include: [
        {
          model: db.Topic
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  group: ['Topics.id']
});
```

Comment: Any errors? What does the query look like that Sequelize produces for your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at it, i would write the code like this

```
db.Workbook.findAll({
  attributes: ['wbquestion.question.topic.id', [db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.sequelize.col('wbquestion.question.topic.id'))], 'topiccount'],
  include: [
    {
      model: db.WorkbookQuestion,
            as: wbquestion,
      where: {
                id: wbquestion.workbookId      
            },
            include: [
                model: db.Question,
                as: question,
                where: {
                    id: wbquestion.questionId
                },
                include: [
                    model: db.Topic,
                    as: topic,
                    where: {
                        id: question.topicId
                    }
                ]
            ]
    }
  ],
    where: {
        studentId : 3
    }
  group: ['topic.id']
});
```

Maybe you can get more readable code by defining the models and relations separately and using eager loading afterwards.

**Edit:**
Generated the migrations and models

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name Student --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name Topic --attributes topicText:string
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name Question --attributes TopicId:integer
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name Workbook --attributes studentId:integer
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name WorkbookQuestion --attributes QuestionId:integer,WorkbookId:integer
```

A simple program for testing the query in console log.

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

var models = require('./models/index');

models.WorkbookQuestion.belongsTo(models.Question, {foreignKey: 'QuestionId'});
models.WorkbookQuestion.belongsTo(models.Workbook, {foreignKey: 'WorkbookId'});

models.Question.hasOne(models.WorkbookQuestion);

models.Workbook.hasOne(models.WorkbookQuestion);
models.Workbook.belongsToMany(models.Question, {through: models.WorkbookQuestion});
models.Workbook.belongsToMany(models.Topic, {through: models.Question});


var res = models.Workbook.findAll({
    attributes: ['topicId', Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('topiccount'))],
  include: [models.WorkbookQuestion, models.Question, models.Topic],
    where: {
        studentId: 3
    },
    group: ['topic.id']  
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.trace(err);
});
```

The result is:

SequelizeDatabaseError: column Topics.Question.WorkbookId does not exist

Maybe you can fix the relations between the models or you should create the query not using findAll functionality.